# Openpyxl Copy Time, returns -1

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, datetime, openpyxl

I am trying to great an excel file that has is the combination of multiple excel files. However, when I copy a cell with a value 00:00, and append it to the master excel file, excel thinks the time is for the year 1899?

Here is my code:

```
def excel_graphs_all(day, users):
    chart_wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
    graph_ws = chart_wb.create_sheet(day + ' Graphs', 0)
    chart_wb_filename = 'graphs_' + day + '.xlsx'
    columnNum = ['A', 'H']
    rowNum = 1
    i = 0
    for user in users:
        filename = user[1] + '_' + day + '.xlsx'
        iter_wb = load_workbook(filename=filename,read_only=True)
        ws = iter_wb.active
        chart_ws = chart_wb.create_sheet(user[1])
        for row in ws.rows:
            chart_ws.append([row[0].value, row[1].value])
        chart = ScatterChart()
        chart.title = user[1] + ' ' + day + ' Heartrate Data'
        chart.x_axis.title = 'Time'
        chart.y_axis.title = 'Heartrate'
        chart.x_axis.scaling.min = 0
        chart.x_axis.scaling.max = 1
        xvalues = Reference(chart_ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row= ws.max_row)
        yvalues = Reference(chart_ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row= ws.max_row)
        series = Series(yvalues, xvalues, title='Heartrate')
        chart.series.append(series)
        spot = columnNum[i % 2]+str(rowNum)
        graph_ws.add_chart(chart, spot)
        if ((i+1)%2)== 0:
            rowNum += 16
        i += 1
    chart_wb.save(chart_wb_filename)
    return chart_wb_filename
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by value `00:00`? Excel uses formatting and not typing for dates and times. From the specification:

> When using the 1900 date system, which has a base date of 30th
>   December 1899, a serial date- time of 1.5 represents midday on the
>   31st December 1899

It sounds like you just need to check the formatting for the relevant cells.

Comment: Basically the data I am saving has the value 0:00:00 and when I try and copy the value from one excel doc to another one, the new excel doc copied value is -1 instead of 0:00:00.

Comment: That doesn't make any kind of sense and is not visible in your code.